# @Scheduled for every one hour doesn't work. tried various options

Tags: spring

i need to use @Schedule spring annotation to with cron parameter to run the job for every one hour. I have tried various option but it doesn't seems to work.

Could someone help me with the valid expression to run for every 1 hour?

ex: 1:00 2:00 3:00 4:00 5:00 6:00 7:00 etc.,

Referred: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks and http://www.baeldung.com/cron-expressions

Tried the following

```
0 0/60 * * * * 
0 * 0/1 * * *
* * 0/1 * * *
* * 0/60 * * *
```

Thanks.

Comment: try this `0 * * * * *`

Comment: shouldnt it `0 0 * ? * * *` work ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

FixedRate annotation got worked to run for every hour

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate=60*60*1000)
public void scheduleFixedRateTask() {
System.out.println(
  "Fixed rate task - " + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
}
```

FixedRate annotation to run for every hour with 10 minutes delay. Incase if you want to make an initial delay to start the job, you can specify "initialDelay". If you specify this value, the the very first time job will be started after the given delay. In the below example, the method is scheduled to run at every hour with initial start delay as 10 minutes.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate=60*60*1000, initialDelay=10*60*1000)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
@Component
public class SomeScheduler {

   @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0/1 * * ?")
   public void print() {
      System.out.println("====>> print method()...");
   }
}

@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
public class AppStarter {

}
```

Comment: @Kathir- Make sure you have enable schedulers using `@EnableScheduling` in any of your configuration class which will register all of your schedulers. You can make your scheduler as configuration class it self rather having separate configuration  class. To verify your cron expression you can use [Cron Maker](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Spring `@Scheduled` annotation has a optional element called [`timeUnit`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#:%7E:text=TimeUnit-,timeUnit,fixedDelayString()%2C%20fixedRate()%2C%20fixedRateString()%2C%20initialDelay()%2C%20and%20initialDelayString().,-String) to setup the time unit use in the `fixedDelay`, `fixedDelayString`, `fixedRate`, `fixedRateString`, `initialDelay`, and `initialDelayString`

So to run a job every one hour `@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.HOURS)`

For other time units (TimeUnit Enum constants) see the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html?is-external=true)

Answer (score 1):

`@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.HOURS)`

Comment: You need to add some explanation to your answer